# Javascript : Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, browserify

Here `bundle.js` is bundled through `browserify` which includes a module called `webrtcsupport`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var webrtcSupport = require('webrtcsupport');
    console.log(webrtcSupport.getUserMedia);
    webrtcSupport.getUserMedia();
</script>
```

Output in browser(Chrome browser) console:

```
function webkitGetUserMedia() { [native code] }
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Why cant I invoke the above function in this manner and what is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "Illegal Invocation" is usually caused when the invocation context is invalid. In case of `.getUserMedia()` it expects the context to be of `navigator`.

Try `webrtcSupport.getUserMedia.call(navigator, ...);`

Comment: Amazing!!! That worked.Can you explain to me what is meant by "invocation context" here?

Comment: Basically `.getUserMedia` expects its `this` to be the `navigator`, so when you invoke it through a wrapper/normalizer such as `webrtcSupport`, it throws the error because the context is wrong.